# Divide polynomials with exponents and simplify

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The expression is

> $$\frac{p^2q^2}{m^2-n^2} \cdot \frac{m^2+2mn+n^2}{3p^2+2pq-q^2}.$$

How could I divide and simplify this?

Comment: Have you tried factoring?

Comment: yes and cancelled some same terms. @RaymondCheng

Comment: Excellent! For one, start by writing down the steps that you have taken so far, and then it would help me and others tailor answers that will be most helpful to your question.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:

Note that  the expressions

$m^2+2mn+n^2 = (m+n)^2$

$m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)$

$3p^2+2pq-q^2=(3p-q)(p+q)$

Now plug these in the expression, cancel out common factors and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the product of two rational fractions as one fraction, and use commutativity of multiplication to rearrange factors, as needed:

$$\frac{p^2q^2}{m^2-n^2} \cdot \frac{m^2+2mn+n^2}{3p^2+2pq-q^2} = \frac{p^2q^2(m^2 + 2mn+n^2)}{(3p^2 + 2pq - q^2)(m^2 - n^2)}$$

Here, you have quadratics in each of the numerator and denominator that can be nicely ***factored***. 
$$\frac{p^2q^2(\overbrace{m^2 + 2mn+n^2}^{(m+n)^2})}{(3p^2 + 2pq - q^2)(m^2 - n^2)} = \frac{p^2q^2\color{blue}{\bf (m + n)}(m+n)}{(p+q)(3p-q)\color{blue}{\bf (m+n)}(m-n)}$$

We can cancel the common factor appearing  in each of the numerator and denominator, which gives us:$$\frac{p^2q^2(m+n)}{(p+q)(3p-q)(m-n)}$$

This is about as simplified as it gets.